# Why do binary files load quicker than alphanumeric text files?

Tags: c, data, file-handling, binary

I've noticed that when I load/store large data files in a binary format, the program runs much faster than if I load data from an ASCII encoded file.

Why is this the case? The data in my case is plain, with limited parsing involved other than `read()` or `fscanf()`.

Comment: You have to show how you're reading them, because that alone can make a huge difference.

Comment: It might not matter that much in practice. And you could use e.g. [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) which can be dumped in text format, but works in binary format.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `fscanf()` in itself probably explains most of it. `fscanf()` has to interpret the passed-in format string, and then has to scan the input stream from the file, trying to match the specified pattern. That's actually a huge amount of work. `read()` just has to read in the specified number of bytes from the file and doesn't have to do any parsing of the input. By contrast, fgets() does a little more work than `read()` since it has to watch for newlines, but it does a lot less work than `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 5):

Its difficult to say without knowing what you're parsing but...

text files are generally bigger. You want to store a number, that can be 4 bytes for an integer, but 10 bytes (*2 for Windows unicode) for some depending on the value.

Both parsing and formatting can be hugely slow. eg. you want to write the integer "123" out to binary - just dump 4 bytes and you're done. Read it back in, read 4 bytes, problem solved.

In text, this involves understanding how to turn the binary 123 into "123" which is quite time-consuming, write it, and then read it back in - you have to parse the text between whitespace, switch on each character (eg so 3 gets read and added to the value, then 2 gets read, multiplied by 10 and added, then 1 gets read, multiplied by 100 and added). I hope you can see how that can be very much more slower than simply reading in 4 bytes.

Comment: You don't need a switch. Just do `'0' + x`. But your point still stands.